# Creating Legend for a power BI custom visual

Tags: d3.js, svg, powerbi

I'm trying to create a power BI custom visual.I'm currently working on creating a pie chart.
The pie chart visual is being displayed.
I have defined `Legend` as a boolean property and currently trying to render a legend for the `piechart` when `show` property of `Legend` value is set to`true` .
But even when `settings.Legend.show` is `true`, No Legend is being shown.

I'm using d3.js to create the visuals.
Can someone help?

Here's my visual.ts

```
    module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
"use strict";



interface Data 
{        
quantity: number;
category: string;
color:string;
selectionId:ISelectionId;
}

interface PieChartArc {
    datapoints:Data[];
    setting:pieChartSettings;
    dataview:DataView[];
}

interface pieChartSettings
{
    Legend :
    {
        show:boolean;
    };
}

interface LegendValues
{
    category:string;
    color:string;
    selection:ISelectionId;
}

function visualTransform(options:VisualUpdateOptions,host:IVisualHost) : PieChartArc
{
    let dataViews=options.dataViews;

    let defaultSetting :pieChartSettings = {
        Legend:{
            show:false,
        }
    };

    let viewModel:PieChartArc=
    {
        datapoints:[],
        setting : defaultSetting,
        dataview: dataViews
    };


    if (!dataViews
        || !dataViews[0]
        || !dataViews[0].categorical
        || !dataViews[0].categorical.categories
        || !dataViews[0].categorical.categories[0].source
        || !dataViews[0].categorical.values)
        return viewModel;
        
    let categorical=dataViews[0].categorical;
    let category=categorical.categories[0];
    let dataValue=categorical.values[0];
    
    let pieChartData:Data[]=[];
    let colorPalette:IColorPalette=host.colorPalette;
    let objects=dataViews[0].metadata.objects
        let pieChartSetting:pieChartSettings={
            Legend:{
                show: getValue<boolean>(objects,'Legend','show',defaultSetting.Legend.show)
            }
        }
    for(let i=0;i<Math.max(category.values.length,dataValue.values.length);i++)
    {
        pieChartData.push({
       quantity:<number>dataValue.values[i],
       category:<string>category.values[i],
       color:colorPalette.getColor(<string>category.values[i]).value,
       selectionId:host.createSelectionIdBuilder()
                     .withCategory(category, i)
                    .createSelectionId()    
        });
        console.log(pieChartData[i].color);

    }
    return {
        datapoints:pieChartData,
        setting:pieChartSetting,
        dataview:dataViews
    };
}

export class PieChart implements IVisual {
    private target: HTMLElement;        
    private settings: VisualSettings;
    private textNode: Text;
    private pieChartContainer: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
    private arc: any;
    private host: IVisualHost;
    private selectionManager:ISelectionManager;
    private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
    private legend:d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
    private g: any;
    private pie: any;
    private color: string;
    private tooltipServiceWrapper: ITooltipServiceWrapper;
    private pieSettings:pieChartSettings;
    static data:DataView[];
    
    static config=
    
    {
    solidOpacity:1,
    transparentOpacity:0.5,
    };

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        console.log('Visual constructor', options);
        
        this.target = options.element;
        this.host=options.host;
        this.selectionManager=options.host.createSelectionManager();
        this.legend=d3.select(options.element);
        let svg=this.svg=d3.select(options.element)
                            .append('svg')
                            .classed("pieChart",true)
                            ;
        
        this.pieChartContainer=svg.append('g').classed('pieChartContainer',true);//.attr('transform','translate('+100+',' +100+')');  
        this.tooltipServiceWrapper = createTooltipServiceWrapper(this.host.tooltipService, options.element);                      
    }


    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
      //  let legendModel : LegendValues[] = legendTransform(options,this.host);
        let viewModel: PieChartArc = visualTransform(options, this.host);        
        let settings=this.pieSettings=viewModel.setting;
        let category=options.dataViews[0].categorical.categories[0];
        let dataValue=options.dataViews[0].categorical.values[0];
        let legend=this.legend;
        let legendEnumerate:LegendValues[];
       // shows legend
      if(settings.Legend.show)
        {  //this.svg.append("text").text("Hello");
        for(let i=0;i<category.values.length;++i)
        {   
               legendEnumerate.push({
                   category:<string>category.values[i],
                   color:<string>dataValue.values[i],
                   selection:this.host.createSelectionIdBuilder()
                   .withCategory(category, i)
                  .createSelectionId()
               });
            }
            let leg=this.legend.append('svg');
               
            for(let i=0;i<Math.max(category.values.length,dataValue.values.length);++i)
            {
                 //  this.legend.html(legendEnumerate[i].category).attr("transform","translate(" + i*20 +",0)")             
                
               // leg.a
               leg.append('circle')
               .attr('cx',20)
               .attr('cy',20)
               .attr('r',8)
               .attr('fill',legendEnumerate[i].color)
               .attr("transform","translate(" + i*20 +",0)")
               ;
               leg.append('text')
               .text(legendEnumerate[i].category)
               .attr("transform","translate(" + i*30 +",0)")
                ;
                } 
            
        }
        PieChart.data=options.dataViews;
        let width=options.viewport.width;
        let height=options.viewport.height;
        let radius=Math.min(width,height)/2;
        this.svg.attr({
            width: width-20,
            height: height-20,
        
        });
        
        this.arc=d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(radius-20);
        this.pie = d3.layout.pie<Data>().value((d: Data):number => d.quantity).sort(null);
        let fill = ((d):string=> d.data.color);
        let tf   =  (d: Data) => `translate(${this.arc.centroid(d)})`;
        let text = d => d.data.category;
        this.svg.append('g');
       
        this.g=this.svg.selectAll('.arc')
                .data(this.pie(viewModel.datapoints))
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .data(this.pie(viewModel.datapoints))
               // .attr("fill",fill)
                ;
               
       let path= this.g.append('path')
                .attr('d', this.arc)
                .attr('fill',fill)
                .attr('fill-opacity',1)
                //.style("stroke","black")
                .attr("stroke-width","0.8");           
                this.g.append('text').attr('transform', tf).text(text).attr('fill',"white");
         
                this.tooltipServiceWrapper.addTooltip(path, 
                (tooltipEvent: TooltipEventArgs<number>) => PieChart.getTooltipData(tooltipEvent.data),
                (tooltipEvent: TooltipEventArgs<number>) => null);
        let selectionManager = this.selectionManager;

            path.on("click",function(d)
             {
                // path.attr('fill','blue');
                selectionManager.select(d.data.selectionId).then((ids: ISelectionId[])=>                    
               {                     
                path.attr('fill-opacity',ids.length>0? PieChart.config.transparentOpacity:PieChart.config.solidOpacity);
                d3.select(this).attr('fill-opacity',PieChart.config.solidOpacity);
                    (<Event>d3.event).stopPropagation;
                });
            });
            path.exit()
                .remove();
                
    }

    
    private static parseSettings(dataView: DataView): VisualSettings {
        
        return VisualSettings.parse(dataView) as VisualSettings;

    }

    /** 
     * This function gets called for each of the objects defined in the capabilities files and allows you to select which of the 
     * objects and properties you want to expose to the users in the property pane.
     * 
     */
    public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstance[] | VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject {                   
       // return VisualSettings.enumerateObjectInstances(this.settings || VisualSettings.getDefault(), options);
    let objectName=options.objectName;
    let objectEnumeration:VisualObjectInstance[]=[];
    switch(objectName)
    {
        case 'Legend':
        objectEnumeration.push({
            objectName:objectName,
            properties:{
                show:this.pieSettings.Legend.show,
            },
            selector:null
        });
    };

    return objectEnumeration;
    
    }

    private static getTooltipData(value: any): VisualTooltipDataItem[] {
        return [{
            displayName:PieChart.data[0].metadata.columns[1].displayName,
            value: value.value.toString(),
            color: value.data.color,
            header:value.data.category
        }];
    }

}
}
```

here's my capabilities.json

```
{
"dataRoles": [
    {
        "displayName": "Category",
        "name": "category",
        "kind": "Grouping"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Measure",
        "name": "measure",
        "kind": "Measure"
    }
],
"objects": {        
    "dataPoint": {
        "displayName": "Data colors",
        "properties": {
            "defaultColor": {
                "displayName": "Default color",
                "type": {
                    "fill": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },                
            "showAllDataPoints": {
                "displayName": "Show all",
                "type": {
                    "bool": true
                }
            },
            "fill": {
                "displayName": "Fill",
                "type": {
                    "fill": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "fillRule": {
                "displayName": "Color saturation",
                "type": {
                    "fill": {}
                }
            },
             "fontSize": {
                "displayName": "Text Size",
                "type": {
                    "formatting": {
                        "fontSize": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Legend":{
        "displayName": "Legend",
        "properties": {
        "show" :{
            "displayName": "Legend",
            "type": {
                "bool": true
            }
        }
    }
    }
},
"dataViewMappings": [
    {
        "categorical": {
            "categories": {
                "for": {
                    "in": "category"
                },
                "dataReductionAlgorithm": {
                    "top": {}
                }
            },
            "values": {
                "select": [
                    {
                        "bind": {
                            "to": "measure"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "conditions":[
           { "category":{
                "max":1
                },
            "measure":{
                "max":1
                }
            }  
            ]
     }        
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does settings.Legend.show evaluate to true when your code executes? What do you see? Do some of the relevant svg elements appear but not the final legend? Please revise the question in line with the Stack Overflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid downvoting by the community

Comment: 1) Are you sure `settings.Legend.show` is updating properly? Have you tried to display the actual runtime value, for example with `window.alert()`? 2) Is legend displaying when you remove the condition check?

Comment: yes `setting.Legend.show` is being updated properly. And Yes, I have tried displaying the Legend without the condition check , but no luck.

Comment: So that is the first of approximately 30 lines of legend code debugged; Perhaps you could narrow that down to 5 lines with some debugging console.log statements?

Perhaps:
1. Check that your d3.selectors actually return valid selections.

2. Look at this.legend.append('svg'). Do you really want to add an svg tag within an svg document?

3. The d3 approach to populating a legend would be with some sort of data or datum join onto a suitable container element and then let d3 create each legend item for you. Looping to add components misses some of the main utility of the library.